# accordion heading glyphon icon not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am using this code for my heading:

```
<div class="accordion-class" accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <div accordion-group is-open="status.open">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                                 <div accordion-heading>
                                <s:text name="detalleExpediente.dlg.BloqueF1" />
                                <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                                    ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-up': !status.open}"></i>
                                 </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
.........
```

And my CSS style:

```
.panel-group .panel-default .panel-heading h4{ width: 100% }
.panel-heading .pull-right { padding: 8px 10px; padding: 0px 10px\0/; }
.panel-heading .pull-right.glyphicon-chevron-up,  .panel-heading .pull-right.glyphicon-chevron-down { background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.panel-heading .pull-right.glyphicon-chevron-up { background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-191-circle-plus.png"); }
.panel-heading .pull-right.glyphicon-chevron-down { background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-192-circle-minus.png"); }
.glyphicon-chevron-right, .glyphicon-chevron-right::before { content:"" !important; }
.glyphicon-chevron-down, .glyphicon-chevron-down::before { content:"" !important; }
```

I have these two images in my folders, they are of the same size.

[image]

[image]

The question is, if we click on the icon, they are changing size, but I want them to remain the same size. Also, there's something strange on the "+" icon. Let me show the current effect in gif:

[image]

How to remain the size and position of these two icons so the width of row will not change??

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have this site live ?

Comment: you want to use `font` or you want to use `icon` as from the `.gif` it seems like missing font has causing the issue.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay i want to use the .gif, but as glyphicon they are font actually. I don't know what to do.

Comment: And @Vinayak sorry I don't have the fiddle, coz I need to put these gifs in a folder I guess? Or the site cannot read the file.  I don't know how to do this in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Make position: absolute of icons it'll not increase the size of row. And when you click on icon make that icon position: absolute as well.

For setting postion of icon you can either use float right or you can go with top : (required according to row)px & right : (required according to row)px.

you can go with z-index as well.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you re doing this

```
.glyphicon-chevron-down, .glyphicon-chevron-down::before { content:"" !important; }
```

to remove the glyph that bootstrap has.

However you don't have something equivalent for chevron-up, which would explaint the position shift when you toggle. So change this to

```
.glyphicon-chevron-down, .glyphicon-chevron-down::before { content:"\00a0" !important; }
```

`\00a0` replaces the existing glyph with a space instead of a blank string.

---

Alternatively add an equivalent CSS ruleset of chevron-up.